# AngularJS $routeProvider not displaying view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically, when I navigate to `http://localhost:9000` in my browser, I receive the content on the index.html page, but ng-view remains completely empty, despite `'/'` being pointed to my controller/view.

Upon first navigation, Angular does *not* add the `/#/` to my url, and `$location.path()` reads an empty string. After clicking any link, the about page for example, Angular adds `/#/about` to my url and the page loads normally. If for any reason, however, the page gets reloaded (I hit reload or live-reload updates), the `/#/about` remains in the url, but ng-view is an empty element.

The config:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
      controller: 'AboutCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
})
```

I included `ngRoute` in the app *and* the script has been added to the index.

This app was working *just fine* before. I experimented with `$locationProvider.html5Mode()` a little and didn't like the results, so I did a hard reset to the git HEAD. After that, it has failed to work as intended on any machine, any browser.

I don't know what could be causing it or what else may be need to solve this. Open to try anything that works at this point.

**EDIT:** StackOverflow managed to remove a portion of my title. .-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after a ton of digging, other people, and trial/error.

If `$scope.apply()` is called to early, it can cancel the digestion that triggers on page load. Using `$timeout` over the method solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to call $location.path('/') in your app.run so that it navigates once angular loads up.

Comment: While that does _visually_ added the `/#/` to the url, the view still does not display after reload or on first navigation.